# Flash size in boards.txt ATmega 328p 32u4

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328, arduino-leonardo, atmega32u4

The ATmega328p and ATmega32u4 microcontroller have 32Kb of flash memory (as datasheet). Bootloader for each microcontroleer has different size (about 512 byte for 328p and 4kb for 32u4).

Why in boards.txt the "upload.maximum_size" parameters is 32256 for 328p and 28672 for 32u4?

I we have to consider bootloader size, the "upload.maximum_size" parameter for 328p must be about 31.5k and not 32k. And, if we do not have to consider bootloader size, as the default boards.txt configuration (above) for 328p, the "upload.maximum_size" parameter for 32u4 must be 32k not 28k. Correct?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1KB` is 1024 bytes, not 1000 bytes.

Therefore 32kb = 32768 bytes.

`32768-512=32256`, which is exactly the value used for upload.maximum_size for the 328p.

4kb=4096 bytes. `32768-4096=28672` which is the value for the 32u4.

Comment: You are right @Gerben. Excuse me for my attention fault. I found [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/20479/atmega32u4-leonardo-pro-micro-bootloader-8k-rather-than-4k) thread about 32u4 flash size. Is it possible the available flash (with bootloader) be less then ~28k because USB stack (as questioned in thread)?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The 32u4 bootloader has to implement the USB stack, which the 328p only has to do UART, which is a lot simpler.